# (TS)Property Rows does not exist on type HTMLInputElemet

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

Hi I am new to angular and type script..I need to check whether table is empty or not and depending upon that I need to hide or display a div. I tried,

`var rows = document.getElementById('associatedEmailsTable'))rows;` and
`var rows =(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('associatedEmailsTable')).rows;`

but both are giving same result, Please help me in this.

Please suggest me how can I find whether table tr has any value inside it or not using javascript.

and My HTML code is

```
   <table class="table table-sm table-hover" id="associatedEmailsTable" style="display:none">
       <tr>
            <th>
              Email
            </th>
            <th>
              Action
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let oEmailAddress of this.associatedEmailAddresses">
            <td>{{oEmailAddress.email}}</td>

          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: whats your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly what the error says, "Property Rows does not exist on type HTMLInputElemet".

Assuming that you have `<table id="associatedEmailsTable">...` then what you have is a `HTMLTableElement`.
So:

```
var rows = (document.getElementById('associatedEmailsTable') as HTMLTableElement).rows;
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, Can you help me to find where can I find documents for these things?

Comment: Not sure, sorry mate. I usually just start typing and pick the most relevant option from autocomplete (using VS Code). When it comes to HTML elements, they all start with HTML...